# Deforming a shape when resizing an OpenGL window

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I draw an object using a shader program and a VAO
But when I deform the window, my figure also deforms.
My vertex shader doesn't do anything, the fragment shader only sets the color orange.

**vertshader.vert**

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
 
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

**gl init function**

```
float vertexes_normalized[12] =
                 {-0.5, 0.5, 0,
                   0.5, 0.5, 0,
                   0.5, -0.5, 0,
                  -0.5, -0.5, 0};

glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(-this->width() / 2, this->width() / 2, -this->height() / 2, this->height() / 2);
glViewport(0, 0, this->width(), this->height());

//Compile shader program
unsigned int shaderProgram = makeShaderProgram(":/glshaders/vertshader.vert", ":/glshaders/fragshader.frag");
if(!shaderProgram) {
    qDebug("[ERROR]initializeGL: makeShaderProgram failed!");
    return;
}
gShaderProgram = shaderProgram;

//Vertex buffer object
unsigned int VBO = 0;
//Allocate 1 buffer
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
//Linking a buffer object to an OpenGL buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
//Copying vertex data from the array to VBO
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexes_normalized), vertexes_normalized, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
gVBO = VBO;

//Configuring the interpretation of the vertex buffer data
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
```

In the drawing function, I just do:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 0, 4);
```

I also have a function that is called during window resizing

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(-newW / 2, newW / 2, -newH / 2, newH / 2);
glViewport(0, 0, newW, newH);
```

This is what I get when I run the program for the first time

[image: First]

However here is what happens if I resize the window

[image: Two]

If I use a regular render using `glBegin(); glVertex(); glEnd();` without a shader program, then everything works fine and the shape does not deform when the window changes.

How can I achieve the same using VBO and VAO?

Comment: `gluOrtho2D` has no effect when you use a shader program. You must use a matrix [Uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)).

Comment: @Rabbid76, I understood.
So all the actions(scaling, rotating, changing the position) with the object I have to perform inside the vertex shader?

Comment: Yes exactly. Use uniforms for the projection, view and  model matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mix the deprecated OpenGL matrices with "modern" OpenGL. `gluOrtho2D` has no effect when you use a shader program. You must use a matrix [Uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)) variable.

---

Add a [Uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)) variable of type `mat4` to the shader program and multiply the vertex coordinates by the matrix:

```c
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
 
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

Get the location index of the uniform after the shader program is linked (after `glLinkProgram`) with [`glGetUniformLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetUniformLocation.xhtml):

```cpp
GLint projection_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection");
```

Specify and [Orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection) matrix. A option is to use the [OpenGL Mathematics (GLM)](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/index.html) library and to set the orthographic projection with [`glm::ortho`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00243.html#gae5b6b40ed882cd56cd7cb97701909c06):

```cpp
glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(-this->width() / 2, this->width() / 2, -this->height() / 2, this->height() / 2);
```

Set the value of the uniform variable after installing the program (after `glUseProgram`) with [`glUniformMatrix4fv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml):

```py
glUniformMatrix4fv(projection_loc , 1, GL_FALE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
```